# Custom features not rendering after updating hugo version

Tags: debugging, hugo, hugo-shortcode, versionupgrade, hugo-theme

Some of the custom changes made to the sidebar in my Hugo project are not rendering in the latest version of Hugo. I have posted the sidebar structure for both the old version 0.96.0 and new version 0.120.4.

[Before updating-image of sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENf5P.png)
[Hugo V0.96.0]

[After updating-image of sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmfl2.png)
[Hugo V0.120.4]

What could have caused this issue to arise?

I have tried to update the themes and plugins. Did anyone have a similar problem with their hugo project can you recommend the solution for such a problem?

Comment: Don't forget to show the code for that feature. Also, are you using _config.toml_ or _hugo.toml_?